# Collision library for bullet hell in Python

Tags: collision-detection, python

I am making a bullet hell game in Python and am looking for a suitable collision library, taking the following into consideration:

- The library should do 2D polygon collision.
- It should be very fast.  As a bullet hell game, I expect to do collision checks between hundreds, likely thousands of objects every frame at a consistent 60fps.
- Good documentation
- Permissive license (like MIT, not GPL)

I am also considering writing my own library in C/C++ and wrapping with python ctypes in the event that no such library exists, though I do not have experience with collision detection algorithms, so I am not sure if this would be more trouble than it's worth.

Could someone provide some guidance on this matter?

Comment: I'd expect a bullet hell game to do simple AABB collision checks and then perhaps a circle check. Keep in mind though that partitioning your objects gives you a major boost. You could always look at Box2D. http://code.google.com/p/box2d-editor/ This tool should also come in handy. But you probably don't want to apply complete physics to your objects.

Comment: i was in a class where someone did a ridiculous bullet hell game in python and they could not find a suitable library.  i think they actually made their own in c/c++ too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the simplicity of typical projectiles in "Bullet Hell"-type games, it'd be pretty simple to roll your own collision detection code.

Collision detection would be a simple line segment to polygon intersection (basic linear algebra).  Iterate through all your projectiles and game entities, and you're done.

If after that point, performance needs to be increased, then check AABB collision prior to each polygon intersection.

If after that, performance still needs a boost, then construct a quad-tree out of your entities and projectiles to do "macro"-AABB checks prior to the checks above.

Also, if your implementation/hardware is good, I wouldn't be surprised if doing it in Python turns out fast enough to achieve your needs.

Comment: This is good advice but a grid-based spatial partition will probably give you much better performance since your projectiles move a lot and all have the same size:

http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/50893

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to work exclusively with circles.
bullets = circles
ships collision detection boundary = circles

Tip: Your art can look a little different than the collision boundary.

Then I suspect a basic radius test would be simple and have exceptional performance.

```
A²+B²=C²
A²=(ship.x-bullet.x)²
B²=(ship.y-bullet.y)²
C²=distance
```

if distance is less than ship.radius, then collision is true.

Performance tip: do the math in a way that avoids square root.

Note: this is sudo code.

```
deltaX = ship.x - bullet.x
deltaY = ship.y - bullet.y
isHit = ship.radiusSquared <= (deltaX*deltaX)+(deltaY*deltaY)
```

with a little extra effort you can also test collision with an outer rectangle, (edge of screen, or walls of a billiards table)

Caution: this does not detect "tunneling" which occurs when fast moving objects move through objects due to their speed being greater than the area they would have collided with.  This is something Box2D handles with bullet=true, but tunneling detection can be performance heavy.  I think the ninja game "N" documented some performance tips for tunneling detection, if you roll your own basic physics engine those are worth looking into.

Box2d is my favorite **shape based** physics engine.

For those making something more like Worms with destructible terrain, you may find it easier to work with a **pixel based** physics engine instead.

Answer (score 0):

I love box2D as much as the next indie developer, but in this case its way overkill.

Try [rabbyt](http://arcticpaint.com/projects/rabbyt/) its not maintained much anymore but its still pretty sweet. Its super fast also, it is however an entire 2D engine but can be used in pygame and pyglet. It takes advantage of hardware acceleration, and can do some pretty intense collision checks.

Pygame has a decent collision library, however having used pygame in the past and recently discovering much better 2D libraries, I've grown to hate it. As for pyglet, its pretty cool but its not a game engine just media engine sort of like SDL(but not SDL based).

I'd say check rabbyt out, theres a google group for support.

EDIT:
Rabbyt IS indeed MIT licensed.